# formatting issues regarding a bar plot

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to create a bar plot using specific numeric values. See code below:

```
x <- c("13.86", "57.02", "8.63","22.14") 
M <- c("Stage 1","Stage 2","Stage 3","REM")

hist(x)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
barplot(x, xlab="Average Percent of Time in Each Sleep Stage", 
        names.arg = M, ylab="Percent",col="blue",
        main="Average Percent of Time in Each Sleep Stage",border="blue", 
        yaxp=c(0, 100, 10))
```

You can see below that even though I have specified the y-axis limit to 100, it's not actually appearing that way. Can someone please help?

In addition, I would like a horizontal line for the x-axis and the title to be above the plot. For creating a horizontal line, I tried abline (h=0), but I received an error message.

Can someone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ylim` to change y-axis limits and use `abline` with `h` value to gte horizontal line.

```
x <- c(13.86, 57.02, 8.63,22.14) 
M <- c("Stage 1","Stage 2","Stage 3","REM")

barplot(x, xlab="Average Percent of Time in Each Sleep Stage", 
        names.arg = M, ylab="Percent",col="blue",
        main="Average Percent of Time in Each Sleep Stage",border="blue", 
        ylim = c(0, 100))
abline(h=100, col="blue")
```

[image]